# Are knot invariants topological invariants?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, terminology

I am a bit confused about terminology considering topology and knot theory.
A topological invariant is considered to be a topological property that does not change under a homeomorphism of the space.
But a knot invariant does not change under ambient isotopy?

Is it still safe to say, that, let's say, the Jones polynomial is a topological invariant of a knot or link?

Comment: As an outsider, the most naive definition is that two knots might be considered as "homeomorphic" if there's a self-homeo of the 3-dimensional space mapping one knot to the other. It's probably more convenient to assume the self-homeo orientation-preserving (otherwise Jones is not an invariant). In this case I don't know if this is equivalent to the existence of such a self-diffeo, which in turn implies the existence of a smooth isotopy between the knots.

Comment: The Ambient Isotopy and Orientation-Preserving Homeomorphism of 3-space are equivalent in the continuous category; a quick search gives [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311865/equivalence-of-knots-ambient-isotopy-vs-homeomorphism) for more info. However, all knots are themselves homeomorphic; knots are embeddings of the circle, and a bijective map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. Thus knot invariants are not topological invariants in this sense, since all knots are homeomorphic but have different knot invariants

Comment: ... That being said, everyone will understand you mean orientation-preserving homeomorphisms of 3-space (possibly dropping the orientation-preserving part and working up to orientation equivalence classes) if you claim knot invariants are topological invariants.

Comment: Homeomorphism and isotopy do not coincide for knots in general 3-manifolds; see https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.05796 for example.

Comment: That knots in the 3-sphere with homeomorphic complements are isotopic is a famous theorem of Gordon and Luecke. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon%E2%80%93Luecke_theorem

Comment: @HJRW: if knots have homeomorphic complements, it means the knots are isotopic "up to elementary symmetry", i.e. they could be isotopic to mirror images of each other, or inverses (if you are keeping track of knot orientation), etc.

Comment: @RyanBudney: as the Wikipedia article explains, the correct statement is that if there’s an orientation-preserving homeomorphism between the complements then the knots are isotopic. I figured this detail didn’t need to be mentioned in a brief comment, though.

Answer (score 9):

For knots, the "topological invariant" you want is that of a **pair of spaces**.

Specifically, consider a knot to be a connected, compact 1-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$, i.e. as a pair $(\mathbb R^3, K)$.

Two knots are equivalent usually means there is a homeomorphism or diffeomorphism of pairs

$$(\mathbb R^3, K_1) \to (\mathbb R^3, K_2).$$

Usually you also demand that the homeomorphism/diffeomorphism of $\mathbb R^3$ is isotopic to the identity.  If you imagine the isotopy, it tells you how to deform the knot $K_1$ to the knot $K_2$.

There are of course many ways of weakening this definition, but it is a fairly standard one.

The **knot exterior** $\mathbb R^3 \setminus K$ is a single space whose homeomorphism/diffeomorphism type encodes much of the information in the isotopy type of the pair $(\mathbb R^3, K)$, so for many purposes you can replace the pairs formalism with a single space.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as asked.

Comment: @DavidRoberts if you are referring to the 2nd question, the answer to that is yes, since the Jones polynomial is an isotopy invariant.  Often isotopy invariants are defined in terms of the exterior, which the Jones polynomial is not.   That's one of its more interesting features, but it's not part of the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks   ! $\ \ $